# Get group id back into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

For dataframe

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['foo', 'bar'] * 3,
   ...:                    'Rank': np.random.randint(0,3,6),
   ...:                    'Val': np.random.rand(6)})
   ...: df
Out[2]: 
  Name  Rank       Val
0  foo     0  0.299397
1  bar     0  0.909228
2  foo     0  0.517700
3  bar     0  0.929863
4  foo     1  0.209324
5  bar     2  0.381515
```

I'm interested in grouping by Name and Rank and possibly getting aggregate values

```
In [3]: group = df.groupby(['Name', 'Rank'])
In [4]: agg = group.agg(sum)
In [5]: agg
Out[5]: 
                Val
Name Rank          
bar  0     1.839091
     2     0.381515
foo  0     0.817097
     1     0.209324
```

But I would like to get a field in the original `df` that contains the group number for that row, like

```
In [13]: df['Group_id'] = [2, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1]
In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
  Name  Rank       Val  Group_id
0  foo     0  0.299397         2
1  bar     0  0.909228         0
2  foo     0  0.517700         2
3  bar     0  0.929863         0
4  foo     1  0.209324         3
5  bar     2  0.381515         1
```

Is there a good way to do this in pandas?

I can get it with python,

```
In [16]: from itertools import count
In [17]: c = count()
In [22]: group.transform(lambda x: c.next())
Out[22]: 
   Val
0    2
1    0
2    2
3    0
4    3
5    1
```

but it's pretty slow on a large dataframe, so I figured there may be a better built in pandas way to do this.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A lot of handy things are stored in the `DataFrameGroupBy.grouper` object.  For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['foo', 'bar'] * 3,
                   'Rank': np.random.randint(0,3,6),
                   'Val': np.random.rand(6)})
>>> grouped = df.groupby(["Name", "Rank"])
>>> grouped.grouper.
grouped.grouper.agg_series        grouped.grouper.indices
grouped.grouper.aggregate         grouped.grouper.labels
grouped.grouper.apply             grouped.grouper.levels
grouped.grouper.axis              grouped.grouper.names
grouped.grouper.compressed        grouped.grouper.ngroups
grouped.grouper.get_group_levels  grouped.grouper.nkeys
grouped.grouper.get_iterator      grouped.grouper.result_index
grouped.grouper.group_info        grouped.grouper.shape
grouped.grouper.group_keys        grouped.grouper.size
grouped.grouper.groupings         grouped.grouper.sort
grouped.grouper.groups
```

and so:

```
>>> df["GroupId"] = df.groupby(["Name", "Rank"]).grouper.group_info[0]
>>> df
  Name  Rank       Val  GroupId
0  foo     0  0.302482        2
1  bar     0  0.375193        0
2  foo     2  0.965763        4
3  bar     2  0.166417        1
4  foo     1  0.495124        3
5  bar     2  0.728776        1
```

There may be a nicer alias for for `grouper.group_info[0]` lurking around somewhere, but this should work, anyway.

Comment: Another alias seems to be `grouped.grouper.labels[0]`

Comment: only problem is grouper is not documented, no guarantee it will not break.

Comment: Three years later and this thing is still undocumented. But it's easy to figure out that `df.grouper` has the class `BaseGrouper`. The `group_info` method is defined [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/2e4da9b07d500add644257b9fa317a668cf5e332/pandas/core/groupby.py#L1549) in the code, and you can follow the trail back a little further to confirm the following: 1) `group_info[1]` is an array of unique group identifiers, 2) the group identifier for  row `i` is `group_info[0][i]`, and 3) `group_info[3]` is the number of groups

Comment: Maybe this is my python naivety, but I'm surprised there's not a straightforward, documented method. I came to this question because I want to use [sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html) and stratify across unique combos of a few different columns. This group ID is exactly the single column I need for the job, but it's been tough to find. I'd be very interested to know if this is a misuse of pandas.

Comment: @jflournoy: in an odd coincidence, I have a PR right now which would give a canonical way to access this information.

Answer (score 16):

Use [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) from pandas 0.20.2+:

```
df["GroupId"] = df.groupby(["Name", "Rank"]).ngroup()
print (df)
  Name  Rank       Val  GroupId
0  foo     2  0.451724        4
1  bar     0  0.944676        0
2  foo     0  0.822390        2
3  bar     2  0.063603        1
4  foo     1  0.938892        3
5  bar     2  0.332454        1
```

Comment: nice one, but the assignment of id to rows will probably be arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution is to use `grouper.label_info`:

```
df["GroupId"] = df.groupby(["Name", "Rank"]).grouper.label_info
```

It automatically associates each row in the `df` dataframe to the corresponding group label.

Comment: This worked before but label_info appears to have been removed in pandas 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers do not mention how the group id within a group is assigned and whether it is replicable across multiple calls or across systems. Hence the ranking of item is not controlled by the user.

To address this issue, I use the following function to assign a rank to individual elements within each group. 'sorter` enables me to control precisely how to assign a rank.

```
def group_rank_id(df, grouper, sorter):
    # function to apply to each group
    def group_fun(x): return x[sorter].reset_index(drop=True).reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'rank'})
    # apply and merge to itself
    out = df.groupby(grouper).apply(group_fun).reset_index(drop=True)
    return df.merge(out, on=sorter)
```

Example data:

```
df
  action  quantity   ticker          date     price
0    buy       3.0  SXRV.DE  1.584662e+09  0.519707
1    buy       7.0   MSF.DE  1.599696e+09  0.998484
2    buy       1.0  ABEA.DE  1.600387e+09  0.538107
3    buy       1.0    AMZ.F  1.606349e+09  0.446594
4    buy       9.0  09KE.BE  1.610669e+09  0.383777
5    buy      11.0  09KF.BE  1.610669e+09  0.987921
6    buy       3.0  FB2A.MU  1.620173e+09  0.696381
7    buy       3.0  FB2A.MU  1.636070e+09  0.700757
```

will result in:

```
group_rank_id(df, 'ticker',['ticker','date'])
  action  quantity   ticker          date     price  rank
0    buy       3.0  SXRV.DE  1.584662e+09  0.519707     0
1    buy       7.0   MSF.DE  1.599696e+09  0.998484     0
2    buy       1.0  ABEA.DE  1.600387e+09  0.538107     0
3    buy       1.0    AMZ.F  1.606349e+09  0.446594     0
4    buy       9.0  09KE.BE  1.610669e+09  0.383777     0
5    buy      11.0  09KF.BE  1.610669e+09  0.987921     0
6    buy       3.0  FB2A.MU  1.620173e+09  0.696381     0
7    buy       3.0  FB2A.MU  1.636070e+09  0.700757     1
```