# How to assign a sequential label to pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

I start with the following pandas dataframe, I wish to group each day, and make a new column called 'label', which labels the group with a sequential number. How do I do this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [10,40,30,10,11,13]}, index=pd.date_range('2016-01-01 00:00:00', periods=6, freq='12H' ) )
# df['label'] = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')) # what do i do here???
print df
```

output:

```
                     val
2016-01-01 00:00:00   10
2016-01-01 12:00:00   40
2016-01-02 00:00:00   30
2016-01-02 12:00:00   10
2016-01-03 00:00:00   11
2016-01-03 12:00:00   13
```

desired output:

```
                    val label
2016-01-01 00:00:00   10  1
2016-01-01 12:00:00   40  1
2016-01-02 00:00:00   30  2
2016-01-02 12:00:00   10  2
2016-01-03 00:00:00   11  3
2016-01-03 12:00:00   13  3
```

Comment: Just FYI, I need this because of `sklearn.cross_validation.LabelKFold`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [10,40,30,10,11,13]}, index=pd.date_range('2016-01-01 00:00:00', periods=6, freq='12H' ) )
```

If you just want to group by date:

```
df['label'] = df.groupby(df.index.date).grouper.group_info[0] + 1
print(df)
```

To group by time more generally, you can use TimeGrouper:

```
df['label'] = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).grouper.group_info[0] + 1
print(df)
```

Both of the above should give you the following:

```
                      val  label
2016-01-01 00:00:00   10      1
2016-01-01 12:00:00   40      1
2016-01-02 00:00:00   30      2
2016-01-02 12:00:00   10      2
2016-01-03 00:00:00   11      3
2016-01-03 12:00:00   13      3
```

I think this is undocumented (or hard to find, at least). Check out:

[Get group id back into pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072626/get-group-id-back-into-pandas-dataframe)

for more discussion.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a more simpler and intuitive approach is this:

```
df['label'] = df.groupby(df.index.day).keys
```

Comment: Would this work with `pd.TimeGrouper()` tho? I do need the more generalized version, in case i want to group by 2 or 5 days at a time