# Python: Compute "group-id" for list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples:

```
tups = [("A","a"), ("A","b"), ("A", "c"), ("B", "a"), ("B", "b"), ("C", "a"), ("L", "a")]
```

And I want to compute sth. like a group-id for each tuple. I.e. (in pseudocode):

```
("A", "a") --> 11

("A", "b") --> 12

("A", "c") --> 13

("B", "a") --> 21

("B", "b") --> 22

("C", "a") --> 31

("L", "a") --> 121
```

I tried to turn my tuples into a pandas df with a multi-index but I didn't figure how to compute the ids. I only found a rather obscure way with the [DataFrameGroupBy.grouper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072626/get-group-id-back-into-pandas-dataframe) class. Anyone?

**Edit**

The actual tuples contain a locationname-streetname pair, i.e. `("Summervillage", "Longstreet")`. So identical locations should get an id and so do the street names. The group-id is supposed to be the combination of both. I am not sure how to further clarify this.

**Edit 2**

Since deleting of a question with answers is discouraged on stackoverflow, another edit:

```
("Summervillage", "Longstreet") --> id 1_1
("Summervillage", "Shortstreet") --> id 1_2
("Summervillage", "Nicestreet") --> id 1_3
("Wintertown", "Somestreet") --> id 2_1
("Wintertown", "Midstreet") --> id 2_2
("Bigcity", "Darkalley") --> id 3_1
```

So the group-id should contain one number for each city and one for each unique street per city.

Comment: And what are these "ids" exactly? an arbitrary number?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking but I think you need something like `Hoffman Code`

Comment: From the examples given I believe there is a capital letter in the first position and a lowercase letter in the 2nd. The ID is made by "concatenating" the alphabetic position for each, so ("L", "a") is 121 because L is the 12th letter in the alphabet and a is the first. Edited to add: won't we have ID-collision with ID 121 could also be ("A", "v") Maybe this needs re-thinking...

Comment: @seventyeightist following that encoding we encounter ambiguity, as 121 could be la or au (12-1 or 1-21)

Comment: @TemporalWolf Yes, but it's the only encoding that makes sense given the examples provided (imo). Hence my comment about ID-collision!

Answer (score 1):

Cryptic questions receive cryptic answers:

```
import string

tups = [("A", "a"), ("A", "b"), ("A", "c"), ("B", "a"),
        ("B", "b"), ("C", "a"), ("L", "a")]

ids = {tup: (str(string.ascii_uppercase.index(tup[0]) + 1) +
             str(string.ascii_lowercase.index(tup[1]) + 1))
       for tup in tups}

print(ids)
# {('B', 'b'): '22', ('A', 'a'): '11', ('A', 'b'): '12',
#  ('B', 'a'): '21', ('C', 'a'): '31', ('L', 'a'): '121', ('A', 'c'): '13'}
```