# How to generate id number using python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe. I want to create a unique ID number for each person and create a column based the person and date(weekly).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'name':['one','one','two','two','two','three','four'],
                     'date':['2019-05-01','2019-05-08','2019-05-01','2019-05-08','2019-05-15','2019-05-01','2019-05-15'],
                    "a":range(7)})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],yearfirst=True)
df = df.sort_values(['name','date'])
print(df)
```

This is the data:

```
    name       date  a
6   four 2019-05-15  6
0    one 2019-05-01  0
1    one 2019-05-08  1
5  three 2019-05-01  5
2    two 2019-05-01  2
3    two 2019-05-08  3
4    two 2019-05-15  4
```

The expected result is

```
    name       date  a    id    week
6   four 2019-05-15  6     1    3
0    one 2019-05-01  0     2    1
1    one 2019-05-08  1     2    2
5  three 2019-05-01  5     3    1 
2    two 2019-05-01  2     4    1
3    two 2019-05-08  3     4    2
4    two 2019-05-15  4     4    3
```

How can I get the "id" and "week"?
Thank you!

Comment: Please ask two separate questions as each column must be generated independently.

Comment: Here is how to get "id": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072626/get-group-id-back-into-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Also you haven't explained what "week" means but I'm going to assume you're referring to what the running week is for that date. Try `np.ceil(df.date.dt.day / 7)`.

Comment: Thank you! Next time I will separate questions. And the meaning of "week" is exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @cs95 commented use [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) with division days by `7` with [`numpy.ceil`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.html):

```
df["Id"] = df.groupby("name").ngroup() + 1
df['week'] = np.ceil(df.date.dt.day / 7).astype(int)
print (df)

    name       date  a  Id  week
6   four 2019-05-15  6   1     3
0    one 2019-05-01  0   2     1
1    one 2019-05-08  1   2     2
5  three 2019-05-01  5   3     1
2    two 2019-05-01  2   4     1
3    two 2019-05-08  3   4     2
4    two 2019-05-15  4   4     3
```

Or:

```
df["Id"] = df.groupby("name").ngroup() + 1
df['week'] =  df.groupby("date").ngroup() + 1
print (df)

    name       date  a  Id  week
6   four 2019-05-15  6   1     3
0    one 2019-05-01  0   2     1
1    one 2019-05-08  1   2     2
5  three 2019-05-01  5   3     1
2    two 2019-05-01  2   4     1
3    two 2019-05-08  3   4     2
4    two 2019-05-15  4   4     3
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `cumsum` to get `df['id']` and `groupby` on `df.date` to get `df['week']`:

```
df['id'] = df.name.ne(df.name.shift()).cumsum()
df['week'] = df.date.groupby(df.date).ngroup() + 1


Out[408]:
    name       date  a  id  week
6   four 2019-05-15  6   1     3
0    one 2019-05-01  0   2     1
1    one 2019-05-08  1   2     2
5  three 2019-05-01  5   3     1
2    two 2019-05-01  2   4     1
3    two 2019-05-08  3   4     2
4    two 2019-05-15  4   4     3
```