# how to create unique couple id for linked pairs in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe linking people together. For example,

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[2,1],[3,4],[5,6],[4,3],[6,5]], columns=['m_id', 'f_id'])
>>> df
   m_id  f_id
0     1     2
1     2     1
2     3     4
3     5     6
4     4     3
5     6     5
```

My goal is to create a third column that creates a unique id for each pair of `m_id` and `f_id`. For instance, the following desired output.

```py
>>> df
   m_id  f_id  shared_id
0     1     2          0
1     2     1          0
2     3     4          1
3     5     6          2
4     4     3          1
5     6     5          2
```

**UPDATE**

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072626/get-group-id-back-into-pandas-dataframe) because I'm not trying to get the group ID back from a typical groupby. In my case, I have two columns and I want to assign a group ID based on if the two elements in a row are the same as the two elements in other rows, ignoring the order of the columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get group id back into pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072626/get-group-id-back-into-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @LucasH this is not a dup of the linked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC

```
pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values,1),index=df.index).groupby([0,1]).ngroup()
Out[94]: 
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    1
5    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

With numeric values, can use `np.unique` to get the groups, after sorting.

```
df['share_id'] = np.unique(np.sort(df.to_numpy(), axis=1), axis=0, return_inverse=True)[1]

   m_id  f_id  share_id
0     1     2         0
1     2     1         0
2     3     4         1
3     5     6         2
4     4     3         1
5     6     5         2
```